# Does resizing an outer vector copies the inner vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Say you have a vector of vector:

```
vector<vector<string> > v;
```

when the internal array of the outer vector is resized (and suppose the internal array also have to be reallocated to a different address), for example by doing lots of `v.push_back()`, does the internal array of the inner vectors get copied as well (because vector's copy constructor usually copies the internal array), or does C++ have a way to resize the outer vector without copying everything recursively?

Does C++11 move constructor affect this? Does this depend on the STL implementation?

Comment: As a side note, the string objects will be reallocated, but not the string itself because those are shared between instance and reallocated only on write (i.e. copy-on-write). So it is not cheap, but each string of character buffer won't copied at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in C++03, the inner vectors are copied when a reallocation is needed for the outer vector. In C++11, they are moved.  It depends on the implementation only so far as the implementation being correct.  If the implementation is correct, this is the behavior.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference? I've tried to check the (C++11) specification but could not find any section that defines how the stored data is copied when a vector is resized, except that it should "obtain memory using an allocator" (§23.2.1/7).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the storage used by the vector (the "outer" one) can't just be extended but it moves to a different address, then the data (no matter what that data is) in the vector have to be moved as well. That's the reason iterators for vectors should always be considered invalid after a e.g. `push_back`.

Comment: "That's the reason iterators for vectors should always be considered invalid after a e.g. push_back" -- Unless there was a `reserve` call?

Comment: @Jeffrey, whether there is a reserve call or not, if you go over your reserve, then the iterator goes bust anyway.

Comment: Yes I know that iterators for outer vector should be considered invalid after a push_back() on the outer vector, but should the iterators for the inner vectors also be considered invalid if you call push_back on the outer vector.

Comment: @LieRyan Yes, iterators and pointers to the inner vector should also be considered invalid if the data is moved.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Actually, unless you checked the `capacity` first; no need to call `reserve` if the capacity is sufficient already.